# What is the correct format code for this type of date?

Tags: python, date, datetime, formatting

I have a numpy array (called dates) of dates (as strings) which I thought were in the form %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S. However, I get an error that I have dates such as 2021-05-11T00:00:00.0000000. Not sure where did that additional 'T' come and why is the time so precise.
I am trying to get rid of the time and only have the date.

My code is here:

```
dates = dataset.iloc[:,0].to_numpy()

newDates = []
for i in range(0,len(dates)):
    newDates.append(datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
    newDates[i] = newDates[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dates = newDates
```

I get an error saying "ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0".
If I wrote instead

```
newDates.append(datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%f'))
```

I get an error "ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0000000".
In which format should the date be given?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-get-an-ISO-8601-date-in-string-format-in-Python) helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have datetime in `dataframe` you can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for converting to desired format. **pandas do all for you!** *(why convert values in `dataframe` to `numpy.array`.)*

```
import pandas as pd

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2021-05-11T00:00:00.0000000' , 
                                '2021-05-20T00:00:00.0000000' ,
                                '2021-06-24T00:00:00.0000000']})


df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
```

---

```
     datetime
0  2021-05-11
1  2021-05-20
2  2021-06-24
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? https://strftime.org/

The extra T can be seen after `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Please don't just post a link, the website content might change later. Also, I don't see any mention of an extra T on the website?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nvm, i think i misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the date, just split the string like this.

`date = date.split('T')[0]`

this will first split the date string into to parts,

[`2021-05-11','00:00:00.0000000`]

then you can extract the first variable in the list by saving only index 0

then you are just left with

`date = '2021-05-11'`

```
dates = dataset.iloc[:,0].to_numpy()

newDates = []
for i in dates:
    newDates.append(i.split('T')[0])

dates = newDates
```

assuming dates is a list